# Lightweight alternatives to Matlab in linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I want to learn some basic things using Matlab. I'd prefer a lightweight one in Linux. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several alternatives:

- [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is very similar to Matlab. For everyday use 
  (without various toolboxes) Octave can be used as a
  transparent replacement.
- [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) is also great, but perhaps closer to Maple/Mathematica
  in functionality than Matlab.
- [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/products/scilab) has many features from Matlab/Mathematica.

If you like to program and has a use for the large number
of extension libraries available in Python, I would definitely
choose Python/Scipy/etc. If you need a simple monolithic package
with linear algebra capabilities and syntax identical to
Matlab then use Octave.

You can find many **other alternatives** [**here**](http://alternativeto.net/software/matlab/).

Answer (score 1):

You can start Matlab with the **`-nodesktop`** switch to run without the very heavy Java GUI. You can still draw plots and other things from this mode and it is in practice fully functional, with some obvious differences (no point-and-click UI).